# llvm-ar keeps giving "invalid argument"

Tags: qt5, llvm, mingw32

I'm trying to build Qt 5.15.2 from source on Windows 11, using llvm-mingw. The configuration succeeded, but building (with mingw32-make) kept giving error "invalid argument" at "llvm-ar" line (picture below).

[Error at the line of llvm-ar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtlsD.png)

I tried to test "ar --help" but it also gave the same thing, so I consider the error came from ar itself, but I don't know why. Btw, to avoid special characters all the paths don't have any spaces.

Anyone could give me some advices?